# method on at parent class is not overriding

Tags: c++

I am trying to override the method in parent class Animal speak function but it is not working. Wrote exactly similar code in java it prints correct message but not in C++. Do I have to do something different in C++ to make this work?

```
class Animal{
public:
    virtual void Speak(){
        cout<<"Animal Speak"<<endl;
    }
};

class Cat:public Animal{
    void Speak() override {
        cout<<"Cat speak"<<endl;
    }
};

class Dog:public Animal{
void Speak() override {
        cout<<"Dog speak"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Cat cat;
    Dog dog;
    Animal ani[]={cat,dog};
    ani[0].Speak();
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting "Cat Speak" to printout in console but it is printing "Animal Speak".

Comment: This is called [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: *I am expecting "Cat Speak" to printout in console* -- If you were using Java, maybe so.  But this is C++ where the rules are different.

Answer (score 3):

In the line `Animal ani[]={cat,dog};`, `cat` and `dog` are copied by value into 2 `Animal` objects. [Object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) occurs during the copying. So, `ani[0].Speak()` actually uses an object of type `Animal`, not `Cat` or `Dog`.

The member function call is also not virtual because the object is used by value. Virtual call is performed only through pointer or reference.

```
Animal* dog_as_animal = &dog;
dog_as_animal->Speak();
Animal& cat_as_animal = cat;
cat_as_animal.Speak();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is copying a cat object to an animal object. Ditto with dog.

You can verify this by implementing a copy constructor.

I think you need:

```
Animal* ani[]={&cat,&dog};
ani[0]->Speak();
```